# Copying a UIImageView in a UITableViewCell to another UIVIew

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a `UITableView` with custom `UITableViewCell`. Inside the `UITableViewCell` there is a `UILabel` and a `UIImageView` as shown:

[image: cell]

Upon selecting this cell, I want to make a copy of the `UIImageView` and make drag and droppable to another `UIView`. I currently have the following code in my custom cell and have the outlets hooked up to the `UIImageView` and `UILabel`:

```
@interface MyCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cellName;

@end
```

**Inside my ViewController I have the following method:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyCell *cell = [self.myTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"My Custom Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cellThumbnail"];
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dragImgToView:)]];
    return cell;
}
```

**Then in my `dragImgToView:` method I have:**

```
- (void)dragImgToView:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    static UIImageView *copyOfSelectedCellsImageView;

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        MyCell *cell = (MyCell *)sender.view;

        // to make a deep copy of the view, need to archive it and unarchive it
        NSData *tempArchiveView = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:cell.imgView];
        copyOfSelectedCellsImageView = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:tempArchiveView];

        // converts the coordinate system of selectedFilterView to the global coordinate system. Need this
        // so that the newly displayed selectedFilterView starts in correct location on screen.
        CGRect startingPoint = [cell.superview convertRect:cell.imgView.frame toView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController.view];
        copyOfSelectedCellsImageView.frame = startingPoint;
        copyOfSelectedCellsImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [self.view addSubview:copyOfSelectedCellsImageView];
        ...
    }
```

When I begin to drag the cell I am registering that the pan is happening and going into this part of the code but there is nothing appearing on the screen. I thought that maybe it could be an issue with the image getting released and so the UIImageView is empty, but I'm not sure. The reason I think this is because if I set the background color to red (uncomment that line) then I get a red rectangle with frame equal to the image frame. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you are use the single image dont use the tableview directly add into view and try surely works

Comment: You should not addGesture in cellForRow - it's gonna be added multiple times - do it only once per cell in awakeFromNib or initialization of cell.

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski thanks for that suggestion. Any ideas about the question I asked?

Comment: I don't think you image view will get released. Add a break point at this line `NSData *tempArchiveView = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:cell.imgView];` and see if the imgView is nil?

Comment: Nah, the imgView isn't nil

Comment: are you sure that you have added copyOfSelectedCellsImageView as subview?

Comment: @arturdev the next lines of code set up the frame and then i have this: `[self.view addSubview:copyOfSelectedCellsImageView]`